# Using InStr in MS Access 2010 with delimited text

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to find when a key (Rejects.ID) is mentioned within Roles.Referenced.

InStr normally works for this, but both fields range from 2-4 characters. There are some intances where the characters of ID are found within Referenced, where ID is 34 and Referenced is 1234.

Referenced is delimited by semicolons except for the first and last entries. I can find 99% of the entries by padding semicolons before and after ID, this works for most-

```
InStr(Roles.Referenced,(";" & Rejects.ID & ";"))
```

Other than adding leading and trailing semicolons, is there a way I can find all instances of ID in Referenced?

Thank you,
JF

Comment: Probably not the answer you want to hear, but delimited values in a text field are bad form and should be normalized.

Comment: Good to know, but the source is an external system that I have no control over.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could conceive is testing all possible scenarios: in the string surrounded by delimiters, at the beginning of the string, or at the end of the string.

```
   InStr(Roles.Referenced,(";" & Rejects.ID & ";")) > 0
OR LEFT (Roles.Referenced,LEN(Rejects.ID))=CStr(Rejects.ID)
OR RIGHT(Roles.Referenced,LEN(Rejects.ID))=CStr(Rejects.ID)
```

Comment: That would parse Roles.Referenced into separate values, right.



I am using InStr to join the tables finding any time